# Opencart выгрузка товаров в xlsx - проблемы с кодировкой

Tags: excel, кодировка, opencart, xlsx, ocstore

Мне нужно выгрузить товары в xlsx из ocStore 1.5.3.1. Пробовал несколько разных модулей для этой цели. Каждый раз файл выгрузки приходит с крякозябрами в непонятной кодировке, которую не распознает никакой инструмент (мне кажется просто файл формируется битый).

Всего в магазине около 4к. позиций (может это как-то влияет).

В чем может быть проблема?

Пример данных:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Проблема в кодировке. Надо конкретно смотреть.... Могу предположить, что кодировка xlsx не совсем подходящая.

Comment: Я уже пробовал сохранить файл почти во всех возможных кодировках. Это не помогло

Comment: Покажите пример данных

Comment: @vikttur  добавил

Comment: Это пример поломки, а не данных )

Comment: @vikttur пример данных - это таблицы в mysql или что?